Mysql server restarts automatically
Recently I have facing an issue that was Mysql restarts automatically in random time periods. It happens frequently.
I am using Mysql 5.7 and ubuntu version 18.04 with 64GB RAM.
I also checked with load average and RAM usage when mysql restart happens.load average was below 5 and 20% of RAM used.
Mysql innodb_buffer_pool size is 16GB.
The error log shows:
[ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of page [page id: space=1072, page number=134544]. You may have to recover from a backup.

[ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Aborting because of a corrupt database page in the system tablespace. Or,  there was a failure in tagging the tablespace  as corrupt.

    InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139990836328192 in file ut0ut.cc line 921

InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.

InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.

InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even

InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be

InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to

InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

InnoDB: about forcing recovery.

This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary

or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,

or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.

As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information

collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608

read_buffer_size=2097152

max_used_connections=307

max_threads=1200

thread_count=251

connection_count=249

It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2789070 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f513c9fdd40
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f5228122e50 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xef07ab]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x377)[0x77b317]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12980)[0x7f5693656980]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7f5692952e87]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7f56929547f1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7514dc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x66)[0x10c9ab6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20buf_page_io_completeP10buf_page_tb+0x2f6)[0x11061f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0x55a)[0x113601a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x465)[0x1107a25]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z27btr_cur_search_to_nth_levelP12dict_index_tmPK8dtuple_t15page_cur_mode_tmP9btr_cur_tmPKcmP5mtr_t+0x5b8)[0x10e6fc8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7500f4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15row_search_mvccPh15page_cur_mode_tP14row_prebuilt_tmm+0x2ea0)[0x103d570]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innobase10index_readEPhPKhj16ha_rkey_function+0x1c4)[0xf34cc4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler10ha_rnd_posEPhS0_+0xec)[0x7d244c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN26QUICK_ROR_INTERSECT_SELECT8get_nextEv+0x367)[0xdf8ec7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc033ef]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP7QEP_TABb+0x1cd)[0xc74d7d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x3a0)[0xc6d590]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12handle_queryP3THDP3LEXP12Query_resultyy+0x23a)[0xce100a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21execute_sqlcom_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LIST+0x41b)[0xc9ae5b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x46be)[0xca1a9e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x415)[0xca3e35]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0xb60)[0xca4ac0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x220)[0xca6610]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x298)[0xd6d378]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x154)[0x1255a74]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db)[0x7f569364b6db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7f5692a3561f]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f513caf4360): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 117999
Status: NOT_KILLED

How to solve this issue ?

"How to solve this issue ?" Perhaps do what the error message suggests?

try to recfovers from the corrupted file see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html but easiest would be to recover your last backuo

Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide thread smoothing suggestions. Welcome to dba.stackexchange

Use force recovery suggestions on error log to bring db up at least on single user mode, get a full backup and delete everything and build from scratchs.
